# iPhone App Dev - changing number of rows in TableView

Tags: xcode, tableview

How do you change the number of rows and the height of the rows within a table view?

I have four items and I want them to occupy equal portions, but grouped together to take up the entire height of the screen... How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the height of the rows

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60;
}
```

for rows

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad), something like this might be more useful:

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    return self.view.frame.size.height / [yourArray count];
}
```